# Prevent Intellij Idea from evaluating infinite streams eagerly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, lazy-evaluation

I've been struggling to figure out why infinite streams were not being evaluated in lazy manner. I've spent hours.

Eventually, I realized that Intellij Idea debugger was evaluating them, making it appear as if the streams were not lazy.

Is there any way to prevent the debugger from evaluating certain variables?

Comment: Report a bug to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug

Comment: I think _if_ the debugger evaluates streams when not needed (I haven't checked this), it is a bug. It should only show the already-evaluated part.